I need to join two xmlParameters into a datagridview
I need to join two xml Parameters in a datagridview, however parameters2 is replacing parameters1, and only the xml of parameter2 is appearing in the datagridview.
I need to show the data where the IDCSITORD column has 5 and 1, and the idea I had would be to modify the xml parameter, but I'm not able to combine the two in the datagridview.CODE`
I need to show the data where the IDCSITORD column has 5 and 1, and the idea I had would be to modify the xml parameter, but I'm not able to combine the two in the datagridview.[CODE](https://i.sstatic.net/cYZHLEgY.png)`List<string[]> parametrosList = new List<string[]>();

// Adicionar parâmetros para IDCSITORD = 1
string[] parametros1 = filtro.GetParametros();
string xmlParametros1 = parametros1[1]; // Assumindo que o XML está na posição 1
xmlParametros1 = ModificarValorIDCSITORD(xmlParametros1, 1); // Modificar para IDCSITORD = 1
parametros1[1] = xmlParametros1;
parametrosList.Add(parametros1);

// Adicionar parâmetros para IDCSITORD = 2
string[] parametros2 = filtro.GetParametros();
string xmlParametros2 = parametros2[1]; // Assumindo que o XML está na posição 1
xmlParametros2 = ModificarValorIDCSITORD(xmlParametros2, 5); // Modificar para IDCSITORD = 2
parametros2[1] = xmlParametros2;
parametrosList.Add(parametros2);

dgVisao.DataBindings.Clear();

foreach (var parametros in parametrosList)
{
    // Configurar os dados e bindings para cada conjunto de parâmetros
    ctrl.List(parametros);
    ctrl.Provider.Bindings(dgVisao);
    Navigator.BindingSource = ctrl.Provider.GetBindingSource;

    // Outras configurações específicas de cada conjunto de parâmetros
    if (filtro.TipoOperacao == SASistemas.Controls.Wms.Filtros.enumTipoOperacao.Saida)
        NOMCLIFOR.HeaderText = "Cliente";
    else
        NOMCLIFOR.HeaderText = "Fornecedor";

    // Focar no DataGridView após configurar os dados
    dgVisao.Focus();

    // Adicionar mais configurações específicas, se necessário

    // Atualizar os medidores
    this.UpdateGauges();
}`


Please put the code inline and don't just add it as an image link. Links on other sites expire, images can't be read by text-readers, and we can't copy the code to answer your question.

use following : string[] newRow = {xmlParametrol1, xmlParametrol2}; parametrolList.Add(newRow);
